# Xcode 4 - Finder with Regular Expressions

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, finder

**TL;DR** I want to use Xcodes finder with regular expressions to update outdated function calls.

**Example** 'numFrames:??? endFrame:@"step1*_0??? text=" "' where the question marks are replaced by a 1-3 digit number and * is a letter and just delete all of that.

**Long Version** First off I know I need to refresh my memory on regular expressions but I feel like I'm banging my head into a wall on this...

I want to use finder to update my calls to a function. I was playing ~400 image sequences in my application and it was impractical to keep updating the individual sequence lengths when they would get updated. Now to solve that I have my application figuring out the length on its own, but I still have outdated length declarations. I could go through one at a time and delete them out but I know Finder can use regular expressions...

What I want to delete out is 'numFrames:??? endFrame:@"step1*_0??? text=" "' where the question marks are replaced by a 1-3 digit number and * is a letter.

If you could point me to a good xcode and regular expression guide (Teach a man to fish...) or just tell me how to do this, either would be great.

Comment: In addition to Brian Walker's Response this document was also helpful in correctly creating my regular expression. http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the find control click the magnifying glass and choose "Show Find Options". Change the Style option from "Textual" to "Regular Expression". Type your regular expression into the search box.